# JavaScript Object Literals & Array Literals

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between Object Literals and Array Literals in JavaScript? I know it has something to do with the length method but i don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Literals) has very good explanation of the different literals with examples.

> **Array Literals**
>
> An array literal is a list of zero or
> more expressions, each of which
> represents an array element, enclosed
> in square brackets ([]). When you
> create an array using an array
> literal, it is initialized with the
> specified values as its elements, and
> its length is set to the number of
> arguments specified.
>
> **Object Literals**
>
> An object literal is a list of zero or
> more pairs of property names and
> associated values of an object,
> enclosed in curly braces ({}). You
> should not use an object literal at
> the beginning of a statement. This
> will lead to an error or not behave as
> you expect, because the { will be
> interpreted as the beginning of a
> block.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the way they're indexed.
Objects have name, value pairs which are not ordered. In some browsers the order you added values will be the order you get when you traverse the object but not in all. The name is usually a string.
Arrays are numerically indexed and the order is totally reliable

Answer (score 2):

Object literal

```
var a = {};
```

Array Literal

```
var a = [];
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

PHP's numeric array becomes an array literal or object literal in JavaScript

```
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');

echo json_encode($ar); // ["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"] - Array literal

echo json_encode($ar, **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**); // {"0":"apple","1":"orange","2":"banana","3":"strawberry"} - Object Literal
```

PHP's associative array becomes an object literal in JavaScript

```
$book = array(
         "title" => "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
         "author" => "David Flanagan",
         "edition" => 6
        );

echo json_encode($book); // {title: "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", author: "David Flanagan", edition: 6} - Object Literal
```