# Prototypes issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am just starting learn a prototypes in javascript an i can't understand what a problem is in my code. I'm sorry, my question may seem silly

i got an error like this :
  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

why is undefined? I inherited a function of the user.
can't understand it :(

```
var user = {

    sayName: function() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }

  };

user.name = "viktor";

user.sayName();

var user2 = {};

user2.prototype = user;

user2.name = "segey";

user2.sayName();
```

Comment: `var user2 = Object.create(user)`

Comment: `prototype` properties are associated with constructor `function`s for use when creating `new` instances, not with the instances themselves.

Comment: The `.prototype` property is only really relevant on a function. The function, when invoked using `new` establishes the relationship between the new object being created and the function's `.prototype` object. *...like Jonanthan said ^^^*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Object Literals & Array Literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500583/javascript-object-literals-array-literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to set up the prototype chain with plain objects is:

```
var user2 = Object.create(user); // set `user` as prototype of `user2`

user2.name = "segey";
user2.sayName();
```

Answer (score 1):

For you question correct solution will:

```
function User() {
    this.name = 'Viktor';
    return this;
}

User.prototype = Object.create({
    sayName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});

function User2() {}
User2.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);

var user = new User();
user.sayName(); // 'Viktor'
user2 = new User2();
user2.name = 'Bogdan';
user2.sayName(); // 'Bogdan'
```

And detailed explanation with example.
Let say we have some basic class `Animal`. Our Animal have `age` and `name`.

```
function Animal() {
    this.age = 5;
    this.name = "Stuffy";
    return this;
}

Animal.prototype = Object.create({
    getAge: function() {
        return this.age;
    },

    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});
```

And when I spent some time with architecture I understand that I also need SubClass of Animal. For example, let it will be `Dog` class with new property and functions. And also `Dog` must extend functions and properties from `Animal` class.

```
function Dog() {
    Animal.apply(this, arguments); // Call parent constructor
    this.wantsEat = true; // Add new properties
    return this;
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // Create object with Animal prototype
Object.extend(Dog.prototype, { // Any extend() function, wish you want
    constructor: Dog, // Restore constructor for Dog class
    eat: function() {
        this.wantsEat = false;
        return this;
    }
});
```

Or you can use `Object.defineProperties()` and extend in this way:

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Dog
    },

    eat: {
        value: function() {
            this.wantsEat = false;
            return this;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Viktorino if you just starts with prototypes I thought that this will be helpful :)

Comment: thank's :) I have a little dark in the eyes, but in general it's OK)