# Javascript associavtive array

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array for javascript

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
var person = {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Toh", age:20};
```

For example I want to create

```
person[1].firstName return me John
person[2].firstName return me Peter
```

How do I actually declare my javascript to make the 2 element works.

Comment: Erm... `var person = [{firstName:"John"},{firstName:"Peter"}];` gives `person[0].firstName` as `John`. Note that arrays are zero-based.

Comment: sorry i forgot the 0 refer to element 1.

Comment: There are many good JavaScript tutorials available on the Internet. I recommend MDN: [MDN - Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating an associative array, you are creating an array of objects. You can either initialize it with an array literal:

```
var person = [
     {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
     {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Toh", age:20}
];
```

(keep in mind that arrays in javascript start with zero, so `person[0]` will be John and `person[1]` will be Peter).

or you can create an empty array and then add the entries afterwards. This allows you to choose the indexes freely:

```
var person = [];
person[1] = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
person[2] = {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Toh", age:20};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) to create an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var persons = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
               {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Toh", age:20}];
```

Notice that arrays are zero-indexed in JavaScript, so you'd access it like this:

```
person[0].firstName; // John
person[1].firstName; // Peter
```

See also [What are the best practices to follow when declaring an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11500492/1048572)  and [JavaScript Object Literals & Array Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500583/1048572).